# Fact or fiction: Webkit’s rendering performance is much lower when used in Qt

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

*Using Qt’s Webkit implementation renders much slower than directly implementing the Webkit engine* -- is this true or just a myth?

From my own experience, I found the load time of a complex page about twice as long in Qt’s “Fancy Browser” example as it does in Google Chrome (which also incorporates a port of Webkit), but I hardly think that is a fair comparison.

Any insights on this?

Comment: Just opening QWidget documentation page in Qt Assistant demonstrates how slow QtWebKit is. I haven't investigated the reason though.

Comment: @Nikita, that's because the Qt docs use a different format than HTML (at least not directly), which needs to be converted to HTML and then rendered in WebKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's fiction. I opened the Qt Demo Browser than comes in the Qt 4.6.2 VC++ demos and loaded the [Qt web site](http://qt.nokia.com/) once in both Chrome and Qt Demo Browser to have the web page in cache and did a reload. I could not notice any appreciable difference and if there is one, it will be operating-system specific, or even hardware specific.